# Android application similar to Apple Aperture / Adobe Lightroom?

Tags: apple-aperture, android, android-app

I'm looking for an Android photography application for my tablet which will work similar to Apple Aperture. The main features I'm particularly interested in are:

- The ability to rate photos 1-5
- Basic photo editing (horizon adjust)

The ability to rate photos 1-5 would be very useful as I use this as a method to filter through the photos before publishing the final set (5 stars only).

Does anyone know of an Android application for tablets with these abilities? Premium or Free.

Comment: Not Sure if Google Picasa or any variant is available on Android hence a comment rather than answer, but you could check that out on http://picasa.google.com - is it a chromebook or something that you're using or a phone or tablet? Otherwise try searching for Picasa in the Play store

Comment: @laurencemadill I actually already have picasa installed on my Nexus 9 tablet by default, I've just never used it. I didn't realise it would have such features.

Comment: You could try Google's [Snapseed][https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.niksoftware.snapseed]. It has all the basic editing tools, but unfortunately, I can't find any info on star ratings, so I don't think it supports that feature...

Comment: I use Adobe PS Touch on my Samsung Galaxy Tab. Cost was 5.99 at the time. Awesome app for photo editing but not sure of the star ratings. It allows you to save to your Adobe Cloud Account, perhaps there maybe an option there

Comment: @Curt definitely worth a try, the Windows and Mac versions have quite good photo management features along with basic editing (contrast, colour, brightness etc), and ratings and keywords i think too. Not sure which of the features will be available in the android tablet version though

Comment: You might try this at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

There is a Photoshop version made for Android and it costs.
You can also use Retrica because it has a lot of cool effects and it is free.
There is also an application called Pixlr made by Autodesk. It is free and very useful, professional and friendly.
The last photo editing Android application is Aviary Photo Editor. It is free and very friendly.
Have a great day!

Comment: Do any of those provide the ability to rate photos? That's one of the main features requested, and I don't see any indication they do.

Comment: At what at you reffering? Rating like stars? Or what?

Comment: Referring to the original question